# Is there a way to group a table by rows with a value that fits within a range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [Kanji]        NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [KanjiUnicode] AS               (unicode([Kanji])) PERSISTED,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);
```

The value of the KanjiUnicode column varies between 20,000 and 40,000

Is there a way that I can group the rows in this table so I can see how many rows have a KanjiUnicode value of

```
20000 - 20099
20100 - 20199
20200 - 20299

etc
```

40 groups in total

What I need to do is to try and get the count of rows that fit within these groups. I have never seen any query SQL that could do this and would be interested to hear if anyone can come up with a way to get a report of this

Comment: You could group by left(KanjiiUnicode, 3). At least that works with the data you provided.

Comment: Want kind of output are you looking for?

Comment: And where do you get "these groups"? is it from a table of some kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Used subquery to derive range and the grouped by in outer query. May be there is a more elegant way to do so but this is I can think of as of now.

```
select range,count(*) as cnt from 
(
select
case 
when KanjiUnicode between 20000 and 20099 then '20000 - 20099'
when KanjiUnicode between 20100 and 20199 then '20100 - 20199'
-- and so on
end as range 
from [dbo].[Phrase] t
) t1
group by range
```

Comment: I think you need to add a count - group by to cover the question

Comment: "What I need to do is to try and get the count of rows that fit within these groups"

Comment: Ok. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
select 
    count(*), 
    (KanjiUnicode / 100)*100 as RangeFrom, 
    (KanjiUnicode / 100)*100 + 99 as RangeTo
from Phrase
group by KanjiUnicode / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
        WHEN [KanjiUnicode] BETWEEN 20000
                AND 20099
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) AS [20000 - 20099]
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN [KanjiUnicode] BETWEEN 20100
                AND 20199
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) AS [20100 - 20199]
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN [KanjiUnicode] BETWEEN 20200
                AND 20299
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) AS [20200 - 20299]
FROM [dbo].[Phrase]
```

OR

```
SELECT LEFT([KanjiUnicode], 3) + '00-99' AS KanjiUnicodeRange
,COUNT(*) AS RecordCount
FROM [dbo].[Phrase]
GROUP BY LEFT([KanjiUnicode], 3)
```